# Can i configure the path Where addFile(path) function in spark stores files in all worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark

In spark Documentation addFile(path) function copies given files to a specific location.But Actually it differs from one executor to another.
Because that path includes executors id.
Is there any way to configure that path to be constant to all executors.

Comment: did it work? I see you had accepted my answer and then reverted.

Answer (score 1):

The path in `sc.addFile(path)` is local file path on the **driver** or path on HDFS or HTTP/HTTPS url.

Look at the scaladoc of [SparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

It ensures that the file is downloaded on all executors and made available via `SparkFiles.get(fileName)`.

Here is an example from [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do) book.

```
val distScript = "./src/R/finddistance.R"
val distScriptName = "finddistance.R"
sc.addFile(distScript)
val distances = contactsContactLists.values.flatMap(x => 
    x.map(y =>
        s"$y.contactlay,$y.contactlong,$y.mylat,$y.mylong")).pipe(Seq(SparkFiles.get(distScriptName)
    )
)
```

Notice how the `SparkFiles.get` within the closure only uses the file name part **without the full path**.

`distScript` is the file with relative path on the driver.
`distScriptName` is only the file name (excluding the path) which the executors can use with `SparkFiles.get` function. The name portion should be unique if your job ships multiple files via `addFile`

We shouldn't really care whether the path is constant across all executors. It **will be made available by Spark on all executors** with `SparkFiles.get(fileName)` within your RDD's closure function (that executes on your executors).